# Datatable serverside does not allow to reinitialise

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

Hi I am using Datatable Server Side to my Website, I did a search but when I push in the button search, It works BUT it shows me that Datatable can not reinitialise, where is the problem in the code? Because It works but it displays that alert that it's annoying... First part of my code I just create a function to take all the data of the datatabse without a filter, then it comes the datatable and then the filter..

Thanks!

```
    fill_datatable();

    function fill_datatable(folio_filter = '', branch_office_filter = '', rut_filter = '', type_filter = '', status_filter = '', dte_filter = '')
    {
        $('#datatable_bill_track').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "searching" : false,
            "language": {
                    "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                    "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                    "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                    "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                    "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                    "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                    "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                    "sSearch":         "Buscar: ",
                    "sUrl":            "",
                    "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                     "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst":    "Primero",
                        "sLast":     "Último",
                        "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                    },
                    "oAria": {
                        "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                    },
                },
            "ajax":{
                     "url": "{{ url('bill_track/fetch') }}",
                     "dataType": "json",
                     "type": "POST",
                     "data":{
                      _token: "{{csrf_token()}}", folio_filter: folio_filter, branch_office_filter: branch_office_filter, rut_filter: rut_filter, type_filter: type_filter, status_filter: status_filter, dte_filter: dte_filter
                     }
                   },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id_bill_track" },
                { "data": "branch_office" },
                { "data": "folio" },
                { "data": "client_supplier" },
                { "data": "liquid_amount" },
                { "data": "gross_amount" },
                { "data": "dte_type" },
                { "data": "type" },
                { "data": "status" },
                { "data": "bill_date" },
                { "data": "buttons" }
            ]

        });
    }

    $('#filter').click(function(){
        var folio_filter = $('#folio_filter').val();
        var branch_office_filter = $('#branch_office_filter').val();
        var rut_filter = $('#rut_filter').val();
        var type_filter = $('#type_filter').val();
        var status_filter = $('#status_filter').val();
        var dte_filter = $('#dte_filter').val();

        if(folio_filter != '' || branch_office_filter != '' || rut_filter != '' || type_filter != '' || status_filter != '' || dte_filter != '')
        {
            $('#datatable_bill_track').DataTable().destroy();
            fill_datatable(folio_filter, branch_office_filter, rut_filter, type_filter, status_filter, dte_filter);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#datatable_bill_track').DataTable().destroy();
            fill_datatable();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you check this http://demo.webslesson.info/custom-search-jquery-datatables/

Comment: Can you try draw() method

Comment: @vadivela the example is exactly my code, but my code does not work

Comment: Server side return data is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if instead of

```
$('#datatable_bill_track').DataTable().destroy();
```

you put

```
destroy: true
```

in your DataTable options?